# Android null pointer exception cursor in query

Tags: java, android

This is my 1st time ask in here, usually I got the answer by searching other people post, i have this code but i got an error in this line `cur = db.rawQuery(sel, null);` null pointer selection. anyone can help?

```
public class DBDataSource {

private SQLiteDatabase db;
private DatabaseHelper dbh;

public DBDataSource(Context ctx) {
    this.dbh = new DatabaseHelper(ctx);
    }

public void open() throws SQLException {
    db = dbh.getWritableDatabase();
}

public void close() {
    dbh.close();
}

public int pencapaian(int p){

String sel = "SELECT price FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2
     +" WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.KOLOM_sSCHEDULE+ "= 'Negosiasi'";

Cursor cur ;

cur = db.rawQuery(sel, null);
cur.moveToFirst();

while (!cur.isAfterLast()) {
p=p+cur.getInt(0);          
cur.moveToNext();
    }
cur.close();

return p;
}
```

and I'm calling it on another class

```
public class Menu {
    private DBDataSource dtsrc;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.menu);      
    pnc=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtpencapaian);
            pencapaian=dtsrc.pencapaian(pencapaian);
            pnc.setText(Integer.toString(pencapaian));
}}
```

log

```
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.marketing.hoffmen/com.marketing.hoffmen.Menu}: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at com.marketing.hoffmen.Menu.onCreate(Menu.java:43)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
12-09 00:36:27.483: E/AndroidRuntime(2329):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
```

this code `pencapaian=dtsrc.pencapaian(pencapaian);` <==line 43

Comment: Post your logcat error.

Comment: where is db initialized?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code ? Please post your logcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `pencapaian` is the problem. Please initialize `pencapaian=0;` and try

```
pencapaian=dtsrc.pencapaian(pencapaian);
```

Also make sure with these two lines of code, It doesn't seems to be there

```
DBDataSource dtsrc = new DBDataSource(this);
dtsrc.open();
```

Comment: Oh yes, hit the jackpot

Comment: yes, it works, the problem is the database is not yet opened, how do i tagged this question as solved?

Comment: @Surya By Just ticking my answer you can accept that my answer is solved your problem

Comment: @Surya you are welcome, Make sure you've posted the correct code parts in the future. The code only very useful to answer

Answer (score 0):

1. Your db is clearly no initialized, thats why you are getting that error
2. To avoid a future issue,You are querying for single column(Price) but accessing it with column number 1, thats your another issue, just replace `cur.getInt(1)` to `cur.getInt(0`)` and your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

> Use this query i hope it will work and make sure you register the activity into the manifest file

```
String sel = "SELECT price FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2
        +" WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.KOLOM_sSCHEDULE+ =" 'Negosiasi'";
```

Comment: What is the difference?

Comment: String sel = "SELECT price FROM "+DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME2
        +" WHERE "+DatabaseHelper.KOLOM_sSCHEDULE+ "= 'Negosiasi'";    surya done little bit mistake in query like this "='

Comment: it will execute but not properly access the database

Comment: this code pencapaian=dtsrc.pencapaian(pencapaian); <==line 43 class menu, calling method in DBDataSource class

Answer (score 0):

The cursor columns will be counted from the 0 index so try to access the value as below:

```
  p=p+cur.getInt(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Place open the db.

```
SQLiteDatabase db= SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myDatabasePath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

then execute the Query.